Getting error while running unit test in jest
Below is the unit test code I have written:
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import { getOnDemandEnvironmentInstances } from './../getOnDemandEnvironmentInstances';
import { MockClient } from './aws-sdk-client-mock';

describe('getOnDemandEnvironmentInstances', () => {
    it('should return instances correctly when there are reservations and instances', async () => {
        const mockClient = new MockClient;
        const mockClientSend = jest.spyOn(mockClient, "send");
        await getOnDemandEnvironmentInstances(mockClient);
        expect(mockClientSend).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

I am getting below error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')
  13 |       const Reservations = data.Reservations;
  14 |
> 15 |       const instanceList = Reservations.reduce((prev, current) => {
     |                                         ^
  16 |           return prev.concat(current.Instances);
  17 |       }, []);

I am trying to write unit tests for below code:
import { DescribeInstancesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ec2";

export async function getOnDemandEnvironmentInstances(ec2Client) {
    const describeInstancesCommand = new DescribeInstancesCommand({
        Filters: [
          { Name: "tag:Phase", Values: ["OnDemandEnv"] },
          { Name: "tag:CbzStackTag", Values: ["cbzwebtier-test-ondemand"] },
          { Name: "tag:Platform", Values: ["Windows"] },
        ],
      });
  
      const data = await ec2Client.send(describeInstancesCommand);
      const Reservations = data.Reservations;
  
      const instanceList = Reservations.reduce((prev, current) => {
          return prev.concat(current.Instances);
      }, []);

      return instanceList;
}

I was expecting the test run to just check whether mockClient(mock of ec2 client) has been called or not. But it is throwing some other errors based on actual code.
Can someone please guide what am I ding wrong or what needs to added/modified?

In the function getOnDemandEnvironmentInstances, the ec2Client send method is invoked.
const data = await ec2Client.send(describeInstancesCommand);

However, in the test case, mockClient is created but the behavior of Send method is not specified. Hence, during the run, the variable data is coming as undefined.
Reading the blog for usage of aws-sdk-client-mock here, you need to follow similar steps for ec2Client
import { mockClient } from "aws-sdk-client-mock";
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

it("should get user names from the DynamoDB", async () => {
  ddbMock.on(GetCommand).resolves({
    Item: { id: "user1", name: "John" },
  });
  const names = await getUserNames(["user1"]);
  expect(names).toStrictEqual(["John"]);
});

Please note that the GetCommand is being mocked as well. Similarly, you need to mock Send for ec2client. Hope this helps!
